# Floating Point Error in script, which computes a side plane

Tags: python, scipy, floating

I have already searched stackoverflow and used different approaches like **scipy special library** to fix this error, but without success. I always get the Message: *"invalid value encountered in double_scalars"*.Maybe someone can figure out the code snippet and tell me how to do the calculation with floating point numbers.

```
for i in xrange(0, int(grid_size/2)):  # i -> row (y-axis velo plane / x-axis image plane)
        for j in xrange(0, i+1): # j -> col (x-axis velo plane / y-axis image plane)
            # Compute plane coords
            x_min = cell_size * j
            x_max = cell_size * (j + 1)
            y_min = cell_size * i
            y_max = cell_size * (i + 1)

            max_angle = np.arctan(y_max / x_min) if x_min !=0 else np.pi/2
            change_angle = np.arctan(y_min / x_min) if x_min !=0 else np.pi/2
            min_angle = np.arctan(y_min / x_max) if y_min !=0 else 0
            num_hor_rays = (max_angle-min_angle)/hrad_res

for p in xrange(0, nplanes):
                current_hangle = min_angle
                current_vngle = lowrad_angle + p * vrad_res

                # Trace ray
                # Side plane
                while current_hangle < change_angle:
                    y = y_min
                    **x = np.cos(current_hangle)*y/np.sin(current_hangle)**
```

The problem is that in x are stored values, that produce a large number. Would be nice if someone could help me, Thanks a lot

Comment: I think `np.sin(current_hangle)` is zero, so you end up dividing by zero which can't be done, so it produces the error

Comment: More specifically, both the numerator and denominator in that expression must be 0 to get the error message *"invalid value encountered in double_scalars"*.  If it was just `sin(current_hangle)` that was 0, the error message would be *"divide by zero encountered in double_scalars"*.

Comment: FYI: You can use [`np.arctan2`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.arctan2.html) to simplify lines such as `max_angle = np.arctan(y_max / x_min) if x_min !=0 else np.pi/2` to `max_angle = np.arctan2(y_max, x_min)`

Comment: @Warren Weckesser that sounds plausible at first, I did not write the code myself, but took it over for the execution of a work so. I will try your suggestion, I would have thought of something like:                                                                                             `if current_hangle != 0 & np.isnan(current_hangle):                                                                       x = np.cos(current_hangle)*y / np.sin(current_hangle)`

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser i misunderstood your suggestion at first, but now it turns out that max_angle does a float division by zero. But this is the intention of the Authors to avoid this problem. As I described I'm searching a workaround for the value in x :/

Comment: SOLUTION: if y_min !=0 else 0 ---> if x_max !=0 else 0